# RS232 serial port communication in kernelspace

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a kernel module for **Linux v3.2** to control an external laser, but I'm having trouble communicating signals through the *RS232 serial port* on the machine.

There seems to be a **serial** driver already compiled in my kernel holding ownership to the ioport addresses I want to access:

```
# cat /proc/ioports | grep serial
  02e8-02ef : serial
  02f8-02ff : serial
  03f8-03ff : serial
```

This makes sense since Linux allows userspace programs to use the `/dev/ttyS*` device nodes to communicate via the serial ports. For example, here's how I setup the device for an LCD panel:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

    /* Initialization and configuration */
    const char *const lcd_dev = "/dev/ttyS1";        
    int lcd_dev_fd = open(lcd_dev, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    fcntl(lcd_dev_fd, F_SETFL, 0);

    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(lcd_dev_fd, &options);

    cfsetispeed(&options, B19200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B19200);
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    tcsetattr(lcd_dev_fd, TCSANOW, &options);

    ...

    /* sending bytes */
    const unsigned char scls[] = {0xFE, 'X', 0xFE, 75, 0xFE, 84, 0xFE, 'H'};
    write(lcd_dev_fd, scls, sizeof(scls);
```

However, this is a userspace interface and thus *incompatible* with my kernelspace module. I need a way to produce the same effect (RS232 serial I/O) but from within kernelspace.

Although I can unload the default Linux **serial** driver and replace it with my own custom RS232 driver, I don't want to reinvent the wheel here -- the default Linux **serial** driver appears to support the functionality I require.

Is there a simple way to communicate via the RS232 serial ports in kernelspace (perhaps through this default Linux **serial** driver), or do I just have to program my own custom RS232 driver?

Comment: Consider recasting your question as 'I'm trying to do this (sample code), and I want this result (expected output), but I'm getting this instead (actual output)'. As it is, your asking us to guess at which of a possible 100+ scenarios your current solution is following. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Does this updated version of my question express the scope of my problem better?

Comment: much better, and now we know you're using 'c' (you'll get a lot of better help if you add a tag for `c`). But I still don't know what you mean about 'communicate', I would assume you mean send and receive information, but an actual 'hello world' -> 'world sez hello back' example would clarify what you're hoping to accomplish. Because you have this tagged as `linux`, I was thinking of `bash|ksh` script to communicate with `/dev/tty/1`, etc. I don't think I'll be much help given your c code (haven't done anything like that in a long time ;-) ) . Good luck!

Comment: Why can't you write all your application in userspace? Why do you need a device driver?

Comment: I think this link can give you a good overview of the Linux kernel serial driver architecture : http://free-electrons.com/doc/serial-drivers.pdf

Comment: @eepp The driver controls the laser over several ioport addresses, and performs very hardware specific operations. The serial I/O must occur in various sections of code, and the overall code will be very intertwined with the serial I/O. In other words, the existing code and design is not suited for userspace.

Comment: @Shellter - this question is aimed at those with some familiarity with the linux kernel, who would well know that C is the only language used in the kernel.   Please consider removing your irrelevant comments which only clutter up the question.  It was already quite clear and specific to those able to help.

Comment: @VilhelmGray - eepp's thought about moving to userspace is valid, but if you feel you cannot you may want to look at things in the kernel which do use the serial port, for example the serial console, KGDB, etc.  As a pragmatic matter, accessing *specific* serial hardware is not that complicated, so if you can't find an elegant solution using an existing abstraction, duplicating the actual UART interface code  may not be the end of the world as long as your envisioned range of hardware is small.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes this driver is for an embedded system so reimplementing the code to register the serial ioport addresses in my own driver is a valid possibility. However, I'm curious how these other kernel modules solve this issue -- if only one module at a given time may register a specific ioport address, do these other modules performing serial I/O simply unload the default Linux serial driver in order to control the serial ports?

Comment: I don't know - I was suggesting you might learn something relevant to your problem by figuring out what they do.

Comment: Minimizing the kernel content really is a good idea.  Make a mini-driver that exposes your ioport operations via an `ioctl()`, then the rest can live in userland.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at **line disciplines**. You can use it to attach a tty device to some read and write routines defined in kernelspace and thus write a driver using a serial line. The line discipline gets attached to it from user space and the kernel will do all the rest.

A good example is **slcan** (drivers/net/can/slcan.c). Examples for the libc calls handling this can be found in can-utils (https://gitorious.org/linux-can/can-utils). If you prefer working by book chapter 18 of Linux Device Drivers will give a good first step: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-18, though the book is not very up to date. Some details may also be found at http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/.